# Netbeans background image moves away from other components

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

I add this problem for quite some time when using NetBeans.

Recently I add a jlabel and placed an image as my background, but now when I try to add more jlabels or buttons, those item wont go on top of the background image. The background image just moves away from the jlabels/buttons, etc. Not sure if I turned off a property, or not even sure what I did to mess that up. Anyone know how to fix this problem? So that I can add more pictures and buttons on top of the background image instead of having my background image move away from these other components. I search around, but couldn't find an answer, so Im hoping one of you guys could help me with this issue. Thanks :D

The Jframe layout is set to free design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help [Handling Images in a Java GUI Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html#background) shows exactly how to add an image as a background in Netbeans IDE

Comment: Thanks, dude. Worked perfectly. Found out what I was doing wrong :) <3